# Can I write `foldr` (or `foldMap`) in terms of 'recursion schemes' `cata`?

Tags: haskell, fold, recursion-schemes, foldable, catamorphism

I recently [read about recursion schemes](https://blog.sumtypeofway.com/recursion-schemes-part-2/) where catamorphisms are described as analogous to generalized `foldr`.

Is is possible to write an instance of `Foldable` (via either `foldr` or `foldMap`) in terms of `cata` in all cases?

Comment: Can you make the question more precise? In particular, does any of the answers below fit your intended question?

Comment: I added 'in all cases' to clarify;  Mark's answer was what I was looking for. Happy to edit again if you have some language which is more precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [often can, but not universally](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/04/29/catamorphisms). All it takes is a single counter-example. Several exist, but consider the simplest one that comes to (my) mind.

While completely unnecessary, [you can define Boolean values with an F-algebra](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/05/06/boolean-catamorphism):

```
data BoolF a = TrueF | FalseF deriving (Show, Eq, Read) 

instance Functor BoolF where      
  fmap _  TrueF =  TrueF
  fmap _ FalseF = FalseF
```

From this (as the linked article explains) you can derive the catamorphism:

```
boolF :: a -> a -> Fix BoolF -> a
boolF x y = cata alg
  where alg TrueF = x
        alg FalseF = y
```

The type `Fix BoolF` is isomorphic to `Bool`, which isn't parametrically polymorphic (i.e. it doesn't have a type parameter), yet a catamorphism exists.

The `Foldable` type class, on the other hand, is defined for a parametrically polymorphic container `t`, e.g.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Since `Bool` isn't parametrically polymorphic, it can't be `Foldable`, yet a catamorphism exists. [The same is true for Peano numbers](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/05/13/peano-catamorphism).

---

For parametrically polymorphic types, on the other hand, you often (perhaps always?) can. Here's a `Foldable` instance for a tree [defined with its catamorphism](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/06/10/tree-catamorphism):

```
instance Foldable TreeFix where
  foldMap f = treeF (\x xs -> f x <> fold xs)
```

Here's [one for `Maybe`](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/05/20/maybe-catamorphism):

```
instance Foldable MaybeFix where
  foldMap = maybeF mempty
```

and [one for linked lists](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/05/27/list-catamorphism):

```
instance Foldable ListFix where
  foldr = listF
```

Comment: I think the question was about whether a *parametric* type admitting `cata` also admits `foldMap`. This does not really make a counterexample, IMO. (The question could have specified the goal better, though.)

Answer (score 4):

`foldMap`, being the fundamental operation of `Foldable`, is a better candidate for implementation than `foldr`. The answer is a qualified yes. `cata` only handles recursion; it doesn't tell you where to "find" all the values in a structure. (In the same way, implementing `foldMap @[]` with `foldr` still requires knowing the inner details of `[]`.) Doing so requires [a little help](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifoldable.html#t:Bifoldable):

```
class Bifoldable f where
  bifoldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> (b -> m) -> f a b -> m
```

You can then define

```
foldMapDefault ::
  (Recursive (f a), Base (f a) ~ b a, Bifoldable b) =>
  Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
foldMapDefault f = cata (bifoldMap f id)
```

This allows you to do things like

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree
deriveBifoldable ''TreeF
instance Foldable Tree where foldMap = foldMapDefault
```

(Though you may as well have just said `deriving Foldable` on `Tree`.) For maximum genericity, you may want something more like this (I say "want"...)

```
newtype Fixed f a = Fixed { getFixed :: f a }
newtype Bibase f a b = Bibase { getBibase :: Base (f a) b }
instance (forall a. Recursive (f a), Bifoldable (Bibase f)) =>
         Foldable (Fixed f) where
  foldMap :: forall a m. Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Fixed f a -> m
  foldMap f = cata (bifoldMap f id . Bibase @f @a @m) . getFixed
```

You can now say things like

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree
deriveBifoldable ''TreeF
deriving via TreeF instance Bifoldable (Bibase Tree)
deriving via (Fixed Tree) instance Foldable Tree
```

But now your `Base` functors can be more irregular:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
type instance Base (List a) = Compose Maybe ((,) a)
instance Recursive (List a) where
  project Nil = Compose Nothing
  project (Cons x xs) = Compose (Just (x, xs))
instance Bifoldable (Bibase List) where
  bifoldMap f g (Bibase (Compose Nothing)) = mempty
  bifoldMap f g (Bibase (Compose (Just (x, xs)))) = f x <> g xs
deriving via (Fixed List) instance Foldable List
```

Comment: I thought the question was about whether we can do something like this to every type which supports `cata`. Here, AFAICS, `deriveBifoldable` can fail in the general case.

Comment: 'I say "want"...' - hahaha, yeah this is mindbending. Very, very cool too!

Comment: What makes `foldMap` the fundamental operation of Foldable, rather than `foldr`?